# How to check in my ember 2.5 application if IE browser is being used and if so generate an error page?

Tags: ember.js

How do I check in my ember 2.5 application if IE browser is being used to view my webpage by the client and if so generate an error page? I only want my customers to use firefox and chrome to view my webpage.

Answer (score 1):

There are some ember addons you can use.

One of them is [ember-cli-ie-check](https://github.com/sportly/ember-cli-ie-check)